# How to call external API using Velocity Template Language

Tags: velocity, vtl

I am working with Velocity Template Language.
I want to invoke a rest api to get the response using VTL.
How can I call an external rest api to get the data using Velocity Template Language?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Velocity Tools in your context, you can use the [`JsonTool`](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/JsonTool.html) or the [`XmlTool`](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/XmlTool.html) (depending on the API return format).

```
#set($result = $json.fetch('https://your/rest/api')
```